How to create arrow like stepper using Bootstrap 5 breadcrumbs
I am trying to create a stepper similar to the one in this example.
I applied coloring to the stepper by using text-bg-success or text-bg-primary classes on the breadcrumb-item as following.
However, the gap in between the steps looks like a diamond shape not a chevron arrow that is pointing to the laguage direction of the page (ltr: right arrow, rtl: left arrow)
How can I change the gap between each step to an arrow instead of a diamond shape?


.breadcrumb-chevron {
    --bs-breadcrumb-divider: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='%236c757d'%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    gap: .5rem;
}

    .breadcrumb-chevron .breadcrumb-item {
        display: flex;
        gap: inherit;
        align-items: center;
        padding-left: 0;
        line-height: 1;
    }

        .breadcrumb-chevron .breadcrumb-item::before {
            gap: inherit;
            float: none;
            width: 1rem;
            height: 1rem;
        }

.breadcrumb-custom .breadcrumb-item {
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: .75rem 3rem;
}

    .breadcrumb-custom .breadcrumb-item::before {
        display: none;
    }

    .breadcrumb-custom .breadcrumb-item::after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: -25px;
        z-index: 1;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-top: -25px;
        content: "";
        background-color: var(--bs-tertiary-bg);
        border-top-right-radius: .5rem;
        box-shadow: 1px -1px var(--bs-border-color);
        transform: scale(.707) rotate(45deg);
    }

    .breadcrumb-custom .breadcrumb-item:first-child {
        padding-left: 1.5rem;
    }

    .breadcrumb-custom .breadcrumb-item:last-child {
        padding-right: 1.5rem;
    }

        .breadcrumb-custom .breadcrumb-item:last-child::after {
            display: none;
        }
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="my-3">
      <ol class="breadcrumb breadcrumb-custom overflow-hidden text-center bg-body-tertiary border rounded-3">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item text-bg-success">
  Step 1            </li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item text-bg-primary active" aria-current="page">
                          <i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i>
                      <a class="fw-semibold text-decoration-none text-white" href="/blank1/Subscription/4c084aht14hc67nxhfpa8e9kw0/Signup/Step/Payment">
                          Step 2
                      </a>
              </li>
      </ol>
  </nav>
</div>




It seems that you need to change background color and box shadow here:
 .breadcrumb-custom .breadcrumb-item::after {

        background-color: var(--bs-tertiary-bg);

        box-shadow: 1px -1px var(--bs-border-color);

So, let it inherit background color, and box shadow could be removed, or make it inherit text color:
.breadcrumb-custom .breadcrumb-item::after {

        background-color: inherit;

        box-shadow: 1px -1px currentcolor;

demo:


.breadcrumb-chevron {
    --bs-breadcrumb-divider: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='%236c757d'%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    gap: .5rem;
}

    .breadcrumb-chevron .breadcrumb-item {
        display: flex;
        gap: inherit;
        align-items: center;
        padding-left: 0;
        line-height: 1;
    }

        .breadcrumb-chevron .breadcrumb-item::before {
            gap: inherit;
            float: none;
            width: 1rem;
            height: 1rem;
        }

.breadcrumb-custom .breadcrumb-item {
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: .75rem 3rem;
}

    .breadcrumb-custom .breadcrumb-item::before {
        display: none;
    }

    .breadcrumb-custom .breadcrumb-item::after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: -25px;
        z-index: 1;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-top: -25px;
        content: "";
        background-color: inherit;
        border-top-right-radius: .5rem;
        box-shadow: 1px -1px currentcolor;
        transform: scale(.707) rotate(45deg);
    }

    .breadcrumb-custom .breadcrumb-item:first-child {
        padding-left: 1.5rem;
    }

    .breadcrumb-custom .breadcrumb-item:last-child {
        padding-right: 1.5rem;
    }

        .breadcrumb-custom .breadcrumb-item:last-child::after {
            display: none;
        }
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="my-3">
      <ol class="breadcrumb breadcrumb-custom overflow-hidden text-center bg-body-tertiary border rounded-3">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item text-bg-success">
  Step 1            </li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item text-bg-primary active" aria-current="page">
                          <i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i>
                      <a class="fw-semibold text-decoration-none text-white" href="/blank1/Subscription/4c084aht14hc67nxhfpa8e9kw0/Signup/Step/Payment">
                          Step 2
                      </a>
              </li>
      </ol>
  </nav>
</div>



